# syntax error near unexpected token `while'

Tags: c++, c

**`Programa que calcula el promedio de goles de un jugador por partido`** hecho por Bolanos Alfaro Jaime Sebastian

```
include<stdio.h>//para los comandos printf, scanf y getchar
int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])
{//abre funcion principal
    unsigned char nombreJugador[30]={'\n'}; short cantPartidos=0, goles=0, suma=0, conde=0; float promedio=0;
    printf("Este programa calcula el promedio de goles por partido de un jugador \n");
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del jugador: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", nombreJugador);
    printf("Ingrese el numero de partidos: ");
    scanf("%hd", &cantPartidos);

    if(cantPartidos>0)
    {
        while (conde<=cantPartidos)
        {
            printf("Ingrese el numero de goles del partido %hd: ", conde);
            scanf("%hd", &goles);
            suma=suma+goles;
            conde= conde+1;
        }
        promedio=(float)suma/cantPartidos;
        printf("%s, tiene un promedio de %g goles por partido", nombreJugador, promedio);
        }
   else
            printf("\n\t La entrada no es correcta, vuelva a cargar el algoritmo");
getchar(); //atrapa el enter de scanf
getchar(); //mantiene estatica la pantalla
}
```

El programa compila, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me aparece un mensaje de error

> 'syntax error near unexpected token `while''

No sé a que se deba ojala puedan ayudarme. México Ciudad de Mexico, programado en `mac` con `CodeBlocks`.

Comment: A simple vista no veo algún error , salvo en los `include` que se te pasó el `#` delante. y el while que tiene un error lógico pues la condición debe ser `while(conde<cantPartidos)` , si no se pedirá el ingreso de un dato más.

Comment: Estuve a punto de votar para cerrar por `error tipográfico`. Pero, teniendo en cuenta la respuesta de JacoboCórdova, creo que es mejor dejarla abierta, como muestra de posibles problemas al usar codificaciones de ficheros inadecuadas.

Answer (score 4):

copié tu codigo y a mí me funciona, lo que me indica que no es un error de programación sino algo relacionado con tu compilador.

Aqui me aventuro a especular que tal vez parte de tu codigo fue copiado de un entorno Windows. de acuerdo a esta pregunta [unexpected token 'done'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367708/bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-done) algunos usuarios reportaron que:

> Si estas teniendo ese error debes tener malos *finales de linea* Unix
> usa `<LF>` al final del archivo, mientras Windos usa `<CR><LF>`. `<CR>`
> es interpretado como un caracter

Finalmente se recomienda abrir un nuevo archivo y escribir todo de nuevo **manualmente** así evitas esos problemas entre formatos.